# setting timeout for socket recv TCP

Tags: c, sockets

I found some hints on how to do it but I dont understand how to use setsockopt. I have an infinite while loop calling recv, I want to timeout and `close(cli_socket)` if client doesnt send anything in 5 seconds.

If client sends only part of the whole expected message I want to reset timer and give him another 5 seconds.

currentry I have this:

```
while((cut = buffer.find("\r\n")) == -1)
        {
            struct timeval tv;
            tv.tv_sec = 5;
            setsockopt(cli_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(struct timeval *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
            recv(cli_socket, tmpBuffer, 100, 0);
            buffer += tmpBuffer;
            memset(tmpBuffer, 0, 100);
        }
```

Comment: You `setsockopt` call seems alright to me, and it works for me. What behavior are you seeing and how does it differ from what you expect? I do notice that you don't check the return value from `recv()`, and that does make me wonder what you expect would happen if it times out.

Comment: I want to close connection if it timeouts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should test the return of `recv` and `break` your loop if it is `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`:

> EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
>   The socket is marked nonblocking and the receive operation would block, or a receive timeout had been set and the timeout expired before data was received

```
struct timeval tv = {5, 0};
setsockopt(cli_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (struct timeval *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));

while((cut = buffer.find("\r\n")) == -1)
{
    int numBytes = recv(cli_socket, tmpBuffer, 100, 0));

    /// Edit: recv does not return EAGAIN else, it return -1 on error.
    /// and in case of timeout, errno is set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK

    if (numBytes <= 0)
    {
        // nothing received from client in last 5 seconds
        break;
    }

    buffer.append(tmpBuffer, numBytes);
}
```

You can also use `select` function which is not so complicated to use:

```
while((cut = buffer.find("\r\n")) == -1)
{
    timeval timeout = { 5, 0 };
    fd_set in_set;

    FD_ZERO(&in_set);
    FD_SET(cli_socket, &in_set);

    // select the set
    int cnt = select(cli_socket + 1, &in_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if (FD_ISSET(cli_socket, &in_set))
    {
        int numBytes = recv(cli_socket, tmpBuffer, 100, 0));
        if (numBytes <= 0)
        {
            // nothing received from client
            break;
        }

        buffer.append(tmpBuffer, numBytes);
    }
    else
    {
        // nothing received from client in last 5 seconds
        break;       
    }
}
```

Comment: poll is much better than select.

Comment: Thank you! I know about select() method, I succesfully used that, my intention was to learn how to use setsockopt for timeouts

Comment: One more question, does above code really reset timeout after i received at least something ?

Comment: @SergeyA `poll` maybe better, but is part of winsock

Comment: @lllook: I think so, but I not tested it.

Comment: @purplepsycho, where does the question mention winsock?

Comment: @SergeyA Sorry, I forgot some words in my previous comment. I mean, `select` is available on windows, *nix... while `poll` is only available on *nix

Comment: @purplepsycho: Windows has [`WSAPoll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741669.aspx) (see [WSAPoll, A new Winsock API to simplify porting poll() applications to Winsock](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2006/10/26/wsapoll-a-new-winsock-api-to-simplify-porting-poll-applications-to-winsock/)), though it is [known to be broken](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/) :(